# Apply a security patch

Tags: magento2, patches

I need to apply some security patches to a **Magento 2.2.7** installation but I don't want to upgrade to 2.2.8 or 2.2.9

Is it possible to apply a patch (e.g. `PRODSECBUG-2202`: Security bypass via form data injection - `CVE-2019-7871` ) without upgrading Magento2 from 2.2.7 to 2.2.9?

e.g. any of the security upgrades here: https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.2.7-and-2.1.16-security-update

Thanks

Comment: I was also looking for the patch but it seems Magento team haven't released them as a separate patch. I think there should be no problem with upgrading to the nearest version.